# Make app icon clickable without back icon

Tags: android

Can i make my Action Bar app icon clickable without displaying the back icon?

This is my code, it works, I have only layout problem:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my activity layout, what I want is remove back icon, is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean enabled)` instead of `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean enabled)`. The latter do exactly the same thing as former which is enabling home button but additionally put up affordance sign which you want to get rid off.